# Image loading error from base64 string Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, base64, qimage

```
string text = "Some base64 string";
QByteArray bytes = QByteArray::fromBase64(text.c_str());
cover.loadFromData(bytes);
```

This is my code. It's work fine, when base64 string starts with "iV". But in another case (for example when it's start with "/9j/") cover returns NULL. What's the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, there exist multiple flavors of [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Are you sure that the Base64 you want to feed in is compatible to what [QByteArray::fromBase64()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromBase64) expects? Maybe, you have to fiddle with the 2nd parameter (the [Base64Options](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#Base64Option-enum)).

Comment: In general, Base64 encoded data just means that a binary has been translated into data which consists of printable ASCII characters only (useful to embed binary data where text is allowed only). With the compatible decoding the binary data can be (lossless) recovered from the Base64 encoded text. However, are you sure that your Base64 encoded text all contain images? It's hard to see on a Base64 encoded text what it contains. (It's as hard as to deduce it from the binary data itself.) Though, most image formats start with a magic code (which is always the same).

Comment: ... Hence, I guess that strings which start with "iV" may be in one image (file) format and string which start with "/9j/" may be in another. Even if you load images from memory you still need the respective Qt image loader plug-ins for this. Thus, the latter may just not be loadable. To puzzle this out, just decode the texts and hexdump the binary data. Then you can guess what format you have by the [Magic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number). (Btw. I ignored the fact that you event didn't mention the type of `cover` assuming it might be `QImage`.)

Comment: @Scheff I checked base64 data [there](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) and it give me correct image. But when i load it in qimage, it returns me null

Comment: Please, see my other thought: _Even if you load images from memory you still need the respective Qt image loader plug-ins for this._ Try to load an image directly which fails to be decoded properly. - If you find that this not the suspected issue, the last step (I would check) is whether the `QByteArray::fromBase64(text.c_str())` always decodes the whole binary data. Not that it aborts near the end and you miss that as you got something. That should be easy to perform by just comparing (at least) the size of orig. image with what you got in the `QByteArray`.

Comment: @Scheff I tried something different. I created a file and load it via QImageReader. Now I get the error "Unsupported format" in whatever format I save. Files are normally opened through editors.

Comment: That's a hint that the resp. plug-in(s) might be missing or cannot be located, at least. Have you tried [QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats)? To me, it's not really clear from the doc. what these `QByteArray`s in the returned list actually should contain. I would look first whether this is any readable text. If the returned list is empty this is regardless, of course, but I wouldn't expect this.